# Read data from numpy array into a pytorch tensor without creating a new tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

Let's say I have a numpy array `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])` and a pytorch tensor `tnsr = torch.zeros(3,)`

Is there a way to read the data contained in `arr` to the tensor `tnsr`, which already exists rather than simply creating a new tensor like `tnsr1 = torch.tensor(arr)`.

This is a simplified example of the problem, since I am using a dataset that contains nearly 17 million entries.

EDIT: I know I can manually loop through each entry in the array. With 17 million entries, that would take quite a while I believe...

Comment: For now, I'm using a little workaround that's not necessarily the most efficient and/or elegant solution. Basically, tnsr[:] = torch.tensor(arr)[:]

Comment: If anyone knows a more elegant solution I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `torch.from_numpy(arr)`. Here is an example that shows that it's not being copied.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

arr = np.random.randint(0,high=10**6,size=(10**4,10**4))
%timeit arr.copy()
```

tells me that it took `492 ms ± 6.54 ms` to copy the array of random integers.
On the other hand

```
%timeit torch.from_numpy(arr)
```

tells me that it took `1.14 µs ± 131 ns` to turn it into a tensor. So there is no way that the 100 mio integers could have been copied. Pytorch is still using the same data.

Finally your version i.e.

```
%timeit torch.tensor(arr)
```

gives 201 ms ± 4.08 ms. Which is quite surprising to me. Since it should not be faster than numpy's copy in copying. But when it's not copying what takes it 1/5 or a second? Maybe it's doing a shallow copy. Maybe somebody else can tell us what's going on exactly.